# Checking a Groëbner basis for a polynomial ideal in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

I'm formalizing [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.05278.pdf) on elliptic curves in Isabelle. At page 14, you can see how is needed to work with the Gröbner basis of certain polynomial ideal.

My question is how can I **check whether a set S is a Gröbner basis of a polynomial ideal** with Isabelle. I'm assuming the membership problem can be solved easily with the algebra command...

**EDIT**

I wonder if the algebra method does this. Quoting the reference:

> Universal problems over multivariate polynomials in a (semi)-
>   ring/field/idom; the capabilities of the method are augmented according to properties of these structures. For this problem class
>   the method is only complete for algebraically closed fields, since
>   the underlying method is based on Hilbert’s Nullstellensatz, where
>   the equivalence only holds for algebraically closed fields.

Comment: There is a formalization in the Archive of Formal Proofs at https://www.isa-afp.org/entries/Groebner_Bases.html, but I haven't checked whether it formalizes what you need.